# Typescript: Function with multiple generic functions as params

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, tuples

I'm trying to expand this existing function (a custom react hook), it currently takes two generic fetch functions and returns their responses data as a named tuple as well as some auxiliary variables. I need it to accept **any number of functions** as parameters then return a fitting named tuple with the respective response data types (and the auxiliary data).

I tried to use rest parameters with different types but still no luck, can't seem to make the function return the right structure. Any help is appreciated!

```
export function useFetchMultipleDataMunicipio<T0, T1>(
    f0: (routeProps: IMunicipioRouteProps, prestacaoContext: IPrestacaoContextProps, settings: ISettings) => AxiosPromise<T0>,
    f1: (routeProps: IMunicipioRouteProps, prestacaoContext: IPrestacaoContextProps, settings: ISettings) => AxiosPromise<T1>,
) {

    const routeProps = useMunicipioContext().municipioRouteProps;
    const prestacaoContext = usePrestacaoContext();
    const { settings } = useSettingsContext();

    const [dataTuple, setDataTuple] = useState<[T0, T1]>();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (_.isEmpty(routeProps) || prestacaoContext.loading) {
            return;
        }

        Promise.all([f0(routeProps, prestacaoContext, settings), f1(routeProps, prestacaoContext, settings)])
            .then((response) => {
                const newDataTuple: [T0,T1] = [response[0].data, response[1].data];
                setDataTuple(newDataTuple);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            });

        return () => {
            setDataTuple(undefined);
            setLoading(true);
        }

    }, [routeProps, prestacaoContext.loading]);

    return { dataTuple, loading, routeProps, prestacaoContext, settings };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
type FetchFunction<T> = (
  routeProps: IMunicipioRouteProps,
  prestacaoContext: IPrestacaoContextProps,
  settings: ISettings
) => AxiosPromise<T>;

type FetchFunctionResponseTypes<T extends Array<FetchFunction<unknown>>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends FetchFunction<infer R> ? R : never;
};
```

You should then be able to use these types with your hook declaration like so:

```
function useFetchMultipleDataMunicipio<T extends Array<FetchFunction<unknown>>>(...args: T) {
     // ...
     const [dataTuple, setDataTuple] =
      useState<FetchFunctionResponseTypes<typeof args>>();

     // ...
     useEffect(() => {
         const promises = args.map(func => func(routeProps, prestacaoContext, settings));
         Promise.all(promises)
           .then((response) => {
             const newDataTuple = response.map(
               (res) => res.data
             ) as FetchFunctionResponseTypes<T>;
             setDataTuple(newDataTuple);
           })
           .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
          });
     }, [routeProps, prestacaoContext.loading]);

     return { dataTuple, loading, routeProps, prestacaoContext, settings };
}
```

Comment: That works flawlessly, thank you Ben